# JavaScript - Replacing for loop with array helpers

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, ecmascript-6

So today I was learning about some ES6 array helpers, and I wanted to change my existing for loops with them, but I can not get same result as i was taking with for loop

```
function comment(){
    let index;
    for(let i = 0; i < commentArray.length; i++){
        if(commentArray[i]._id == req.params.commentId){
            index = commentArray.indexOf(commentArray[i]);
        }
    }
    return index;
}
var com = comment();
```

It is nodejs and I am trying to get element index from database, and than pull from it, my code works just fine, but I want to change it with array helper, I guess I need find helper, but I can not make it work!

Comment: And what's your code with "array helpers"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace your for loop with this one-liner which uses [`Array#findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex):

```
let index = commentArray.findIndex(comment => comment._id === req.params.commentId);
```

When this line executes, it will assign the index of comment, which has `_id` attribute same as `req.params.commentId`.

Comment: works pretty well! just change triple equal sign to double, because with triple it gave me silly error when index equaled -1, i guess that is because comment._id is coming from db as string <3 thanks

Comment: @TokoGoshadze -- don't get confused. Read the difference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons) and then make the decisions.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to find the index of the item in the array based on some condition, you can use `findIndex` function

```
commentArray.findIndex(comment => comment._id === req.params.commentId)
```

Also with your current code with `for loop`, I think you need return the index as soon as it is found and not let the loop iterate till the end.

```
for(let i = 0; i < commentArray.length; i++){
    if(commentArray[i]._id == req.params.commentId){
        return commentArray.indexOf(commentArray[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer, it worked, and ill keep in mind to return index when its found next time!